# Flask gives 503 but doesn't log it?

Tags: python, http, flask, neo4j, server

I am running a flask server that connects to a neo4j database and essentially provides data to a UI that requests data from it. I intermittently have been getting a 503 error ever since i implemented HTTPS on the Flask server, and when the error does come up, its not logged in my logs. I send the output of the flask script to a file. All i see is HTTP 200 requests and a few other details I log. I tested the flask server locally, and forced a 404, and 503 error and see those outputted to the console where flask outputs as well as to the log that i send the console output from flask to. It cant be a overloaded server because there are only a few requests going on and my database is relatively small. Any idea what's going on? Here is the log snipped from when the 503 occurred, arournd 7pm:

```
172.17.41.146 - - [17/Dec/2018 16:59:29] "POST /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.41.146 - - [17/Dec/2018 16:59:34] "OPTIONS /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.41.146 - - [17/Dec/2018 16:59:34] "OPTIONS /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.41.146 - - [17/Dec/2018 16:59:34] "POST /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.41.146 - - [17/Dec/2018 16:59:35] "POST /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:00] "GET /inline.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:00] "GET /polyfills.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:00] "GET /styles.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:00] "GET /vendor.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:00] "GET /main.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:02] "GET /assets/images/Cimg1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.282 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:08:02] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.283 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:23:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.283 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:23:07] "GET /inline.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.283 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:23:17] "POST /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.57.283 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:23:18] "POST /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and here is a snippet of my locally forced 503:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:07:53] "POST /getDocContaining HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:11] "GET /empty-view/ HTTP/1.1" 503 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:17] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:17] "GET /static/css/narrow-jumbotron.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:17] "GET /static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:17] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:17] "GET /getAlDoc HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:20] "GET /getDocument HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:29] "GET /empty-view HTTP/1.1" 301 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2018 17:17:29] "GET /empty-view/ HTTP/1.1" 503 -
```